# Change text color using CSS color property

Tags: css, colors

I have a problem with a color property in my CSS

I really don't find any issue

My code:

```css
#header-right-section {
  float: right;
}
#header-right-sidebar {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header-right-section .widget {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: red;
}
#header-right-section .widget h3 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- #header-left-section -->
<div id="header-right-section">
  <div id="header-right-sidebar" class="clearfix">
    <aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
      <h3 class="widget-title">Association de cavaliers randonneurs en Haute-Garonne</h3>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the color of the text "Association de cavaliers randonneurs en Haute-Garonne". But it doesn't work.

Comment: works fine in your question's snippet. whats the problem?

Comment: color is red what's not working. perhaps something previous defined style is overriding. try using !important.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write in your css (maybe an Example for color red):

```
.widget-title {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

you can also give the color an important if it doesn't work

```
.widget-title {
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```